# Extensible application using Qt

Tags: qt, plugins, service, qml

I am working on an application which interact with a database and construct reports, I want this application to be extensible and I can in the future to integrate custom report builders to the application as plugins.

I have some question about the plugin architecture supported by Qt:

- Can I load the plugins in there own processes ?
- How could I send some custom QML type from the plugin to main application and hook some event handlers on it.

Another question: is there any framework to develop service based qt application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I load the plugins in there own processes ?

Not with the plugin mechanism (`QPluginLoader`). The plugin mechanism dynamically loads libraries (different threads are possible). However, your plugins can be a normal application, that gets started by your main application via `QProcess`, and exchange data via stdin/stdout (or other IPC mechanisms)

> How could I send some custom QML type from the plugin to main application and hook some event handlers on it.

In case you use normal plugins, simply add method that returns the created QML object. Have a look at:https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#loading-qml-objects-from-c

In case you want to use the multi process version, it gets slightly more complicated. Pass the QML code via stdout and create it in your main application. Pass some "communicator" object to this created QML object, so that the QML type can send back data via that communicator to it's original process.

Comment: in the case of multi-process scenario, I can use the QtRO Module to manage the IPC ?
Using the multi-process scenario I loose the PluginLoader capability of validating the plugins, I have to manage it my self.

Comment: I guess the best way is to use the PluginLoader and inside the plugin if any heavy calculation is needed I delegated to a process and use IPC between the process and plugin.

Comment: Yes, QtRO should work. But if it's just because of calculations, use threads! There is no need for a seperate process in that case

Comment: it's about calculation and fault tolerance, if the plugin crash I don't wont my application to crash too.

Comment: In that case, your approach either using processes or combining both is what you need

Comment: Actually I am thinking of using QtRO as services and expose them to the application, regrouping them in groups so the application know what to do with them. It will be limited in some way, need to figure out all the possible plugin types in advance